# x-y Plot based on 2 column table

Tags: r, plot

I'm really new to R and I'm trying to convert a 2 column table into an xy-Plot.

Here's my .csv:

```
x [cm];y [cm]
0.5;0
2.6;9
0.5;1
0.6;2
0.7;3
0.8;4
1;5
1.2;6
1.5;7
1.9;8
```

Now: `` plot(data$`x [cm]`,data$`y [cm]`, type="b") ``.

However I get this result:

[image]

I'm not quite sure why (0.5/y) and (2.6/y) are connected..

What I want is a simple line connecting all the dots since they are representing electric field lines. Is there an easy way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort your data first:

```
data <- data[order(data[,1]),]
plot(data[,1], data[,2], type="b", xlab="x [cm]", ylab="y [cm]")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be my favourite solution so far, since I have a couple of more data to import. However, I get ```Error in stripchart.default(x1, ...) : invalid plotting method``` when I'm trying to plot. I'm sure I'm making a beginners mistake here. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=`x [cm]`, y=`y [cm]`)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

Or using base R plot

```
plot(data$`x [cm]`, data$`y [cm]`, 
 xlim=range(data$`x [cm]`), ylim=range(data$`y [cm]`), 
 xlab="x [cm]", ylab="y [cm]")

lines(data$`x [cm]`[order(data$`x [cm]`)], data$`y [cm]`[order(data$`y [cm]`)], 
      xlim=range(data$`x [cm]`), ylim=range(data$`y [cm]`))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The points are connected like this because the connection is created based on their order in the matrix.

```r
m <- matrix(c(
  0.5, 0,
  0.5, 1,
  0.6, 2,
  0.7, 3,
  0.8, 4,
  1, 5,
  1.2, 6,
  1.5, 7,
  1.9, 8,
  2.6, 9), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

colnames(m) <- c("x", "y")

plot(m, type = "b")
```

Simly regrouping the matrix solves your problem.

[image]